# Can the tag counts be the same?

Tags: feature-request, bug, tags, caching

On the tag home page, I see this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Note the x 7895. But on the tag's own page, I see this:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

Here it says 8020. I guess that one (the latter) is cached? Please could they both be right? Or both be wrong - but the same wrong?

I guess that this is because I've edited about 160 over the last 4 days, but it's odd they're getting the number from different places.

Comment: I checked a couple here on MSE and they are all equal. How long are they different? Some caches expire on an hour basis, some on a day basis.

Comment: @rene well 15 hours later they're still off.